# Powershell to add A record to a DNS sub domain

Tags: powershell, dns

I am trying to bulk add A records to a sub domain in DNS, the below PS works fine when adding to the AD integrated domain, for instance, mycompany.com, this has a sub domain called test.

Example import file for the records to add for servers
HostName,IPAddress
server1,10.10.10.1
server2,10.10.10.2

```
Import-Csv "C:\path\to\file" | foreach{Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name $_.hostname -ZoneName test -IPv4Address $_.ipaddress }
```

Error I get is - Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA : The zone xxxxx was not found

This works fine for the main mycompany.com zone if I test it there, but guessing as this is a sub domain it's not the same.

I have scoured the internet but seems most sites does not reference sub domains.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and the solution is to add the subdomain to the hostnames in your input file, e.g. if you want to add the hostname "host01" to the subdomain "test" of the "company.com" Zone, make sure your input file specifies the hostname as "host01.test". Also, just use "company.com" as the ZoneName, for example:

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name "host01.test" -ZoneName "company.com" -IPv4Address "1.2.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct since it works on my server. However, I did need to use the fully qualified domain name. That would be something like: test.example.com

```
Import-Csv "C:\path\to\file" | foreach{Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name $_.hostname -ZoneName test.example.com -IPv4Address $_.ipaddress }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Booga, still an issue for me even with the fqdn, never mind I just manually updated it as it was just a one off update, found i was spending more time trying to get it to work than it would take me just to update myself.